# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar los datos de una API por líneas en Python?

Tags: python, api

Me gustaría saber como puedo almacenar los datos de una API en python, estoy configurando la API de JustAnotherPanel

```
import requests

url = 'https://justanotherpanel.com/api/v2'

data = {
    'key' : '(key)',
    'action' : 'services'
}

r = requests.post(url, data=data).text
```

Este es mi código hasta ahora, el problema es que me da como resultado infinitas líneas de código.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la documentación de la web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero almacenar cada servicio en una línea de mysql. O simplemente ordenarlos por líneas.

Comment: Al ejecutar tu código obtengo `{"error":"Invalid API key"}`, no el error que describes

Comment: @CandidMoe se trata de una API, para conseguir una key debes de logearte en el sitio web de dicha API. Claramente te va a dar un error, por que el OP no adjuntó la verdadera key. Además esta pregunta no es tan específica, se puede responder de manera general perfectamente. De esta manera sería una respuesta válida para acomodar cualquier solicitud a la web.